# What font does Adobe Edge Code (Brackets) use for its code editor?

Tags: javascript, css, typography, adobe-edge, adobe-brackets

Does anyone know? Also what syntax highlighter is is using? Prettify etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source Code Pro is the font they're using.

https://github.com/adobe/Source-Code-Pro

https://github.com/adobe/Source-Code-Pro/downloads

Syntax highlighting is done via Code Mirror

http://codemirror.net/

All extensions available are listed here.

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Extensions